# Error The file name must end with .xml, when placing binary files in asset folder

Tags: android, android-ndk

From what I have read, binary files should be put in assets folder in order to be able to access them correctly from the native part of my application. Yet when I put a binary, android studio complains that the file should should be an XML folder. From what I read, putting the binary in raw folder is not a good idea, Since the process of reading raw files in native code is not straight forward nor forward compatible since open opens a file stream and seeks forward some offset. If android system designs later on decide to unpack raw files outside the APK the code will not work any more. I there a way I can suppress the XML error that results when I put the binary in the assets folder.

Comment: I use non-XML files in `assets/` all the time. Are you sure that you have `assets/` in the proper place (e.g., `app/src/main/assets/`), and not as a subdirectory of `res/`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I had the assets folder under res. thank you

Answer (score 3):

The `assets/` directory should be a peer of `res/` and `java/`, not inside of `res/`. Otherwise, the build tools will think that it is a resource directory and may expect its contents to be limited to XML files.